# Get github copilot suggestions only when requested

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, github-copilot

Is there any GH Copilot configuration setting for getting suggestions only when I request them? Like a shortcut or something like that... I haven't found any similar in it's documentation

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution? In the same boat right now!

Comment: Dorin Botan's solution was good enough (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72828447/12615886), Although the suggestions are not inline but in a new tab

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable inline suggestions with the `github.copilot.inlineSuggest.enable` setting, or with the [Trigger Inline Suggesion](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/configuring-github-copilot/configuring-github-copilot-in-visual-studio-code) hotkey (`Alt` + `\` on Win/Linux, `⌥` + `\` on Mac).

To ask for a suggesion, use `Open GitHub Copilot (additional suggestions in separate pane)` hotkey (`Ctrl` + `Enter` on Win/Linux, `Ctrl` + `Return` on Mac).

Comment: No shortcut to just reopen the last inline suggestion (I sometimes reject them by mistake)?